# Serving private images using PHP

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to serve some hidden images (not in public_html folder) using a php file. For some reason I'm getting a broken link image and I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. (it might be something really stupid).

For simplicity purpose, I'm storing the image file in the same level as the other files (as it still gives me a broken link).

I'm storing the php file in the root and calling it on my php page using

```
<img src="LoadImg.php"/>
```

Then, the LoadImg.php is very simple:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$img='image.jpg';
readfile($img);

?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the path to the image relative to the PHP file?

Comment: Sorry, I said in the begining that it was a subfolder, but now (for testing purposes) I'm just storing it in the same level as the other files.

Comment: What do you see if you go directly to LoagImg.php in your web browser? The img tag will show a "broken" icon if there are any error or warning messages (even if there is just an extra line break at the beginning of the data).

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the full path to `$img`, i.e. :

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$img='/home/site/hiddenfolder/image.jpg';
readfile($img);
```

---

Alternatively, you can provide the relative path.
Assuming that `hiddenfolder` is located on the same dir as `LoadImg.php` you can use:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$img='hiddenfolder/image.jpg';
readfile($img);
```

Comment: I'm using relative path (for testing purposes I'm storing the img in the same folder as the php file for now). Still get a broken link...

Comment: Use the full path example. Also, make sure the `$img` is readable.

Answer (score 0):

For Apache add this to httpd.conf

```xml
<Directory "/var/www/html/img">
    AllowOverride None
    order deny,allow
    Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

Comment: <Directory "/var/www/html/img">
    AllowOverride None
    order deny,allow
    Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>